# Renaming files in powershell using the folder name

Tags: powershell, file-io

Using Powershell, I want to rename files in folders by using the name of the folder that the files are in.  So in my C:\temp directory, there are 3 folders called 'aaa', 'bbb' and 'ccc'.  In each of these folders, there are 3 files called doc1.txt, doc2.txt and doc3.txt.  I would like to rename all 9 .txt files to folderName+fileName, so they would be renamed to the following:

```
aaadoc1.txt
aaadoc2.txt
aaadoc3.txt
bbbdoc1.txt
bbbdoc2.txt
bbbdoc3.txt
cccdoc1.txt
cccdoc2.txt
cccdoc3.txt
```

Please could anyone point me in the right direction about how to approach this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will rename the files and put an underscore ('_') between the folder name and the file name:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name+'_'+$_.Name}
```

Comment: Wow thanks Shay!  Works a treat, and it's given me other things that I need to learn as well!

Comment: How would you achieve the same for a sub directory as well?
Ie Dir1_Dir2_filename?

Answer (score 1):

`[IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory().split('\\')[-1]` will give you the directory you are in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$dirname = resolve-path . | split-path -leaf
Get-ChildItem -Name | Foreach { Rename-Item $_  ( $dirname + $_ ) }
```

Be careful not to destroy/delete any of your files. No guarantee.

Comment: Thanks John!  It sort of worked but there were some unintended side effects!  The txt files were renamed, but also the folders were renamed to tempaaa tempbbb tempccc.  This doesn't actually cause me a problem, but if you just wanted to rename the files but not the folders, you'd be screwed.  Interesting how your approach differs from the other one - seems like with Powershell there are lots of ways to skin a cat!  Thanks for the help