# Read the file names from text list and use those name to rename the files another folder

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I am trying to code a powershell script to read the files names, line by line, from one folder then use those names to rename the files in another folder line by line.

**What I Want:**

For Example:

I have a two things:

The first is a text file that contains a list of filenames. The second is a folder that contains files.

What the script needs to do is read from the text file with a list of filenames, then rename the files in the folder with those filenames that are in the list; doing this all line by line.

I am trying to research if this has been done but I can't seem to locate it.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify the "rename the files in another folder line by line", probably an example would be helpful :)

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816218/renaming-files-in-powershell-using-the-folder-name) and [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Rename-Files-b1268678) may give you a start!

Comment: Ok. I apologize I wasn't more clear. I made some edits to be more clear.

Comment: What code have **you** tried so far?