# Rename a folder using part of a certain filename inside the folder

Tags: powershell, rename, batch-rename

I have a number of folders with a similar set of files. Each folder contains a file, among others, with filename in a certain pattern, e.g., "Result_XYZ.txt". So this file will have a unique XYZ part in each of the folders. I want to rename each of the folders using XYZ part of that specific file. Finally there are many such folders, so I'll need to do a batch rename.
It looks like a reverse task from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816218/renaming-files-in-powershell-using-the-folder-name), although I can't figure out how to solve my problem.
Thank you in advance!

Clarification, thanks to Keith:

I need to add that the specific filename I need to use contains several '_' symbols and a '-' symbol, so the filenames look like:

*Some Result_123_ABC_A1B2_XYZ-M1.txt*

So the part that I need for folder name is '123_ABC_A1B2_XYZ-M1'.
I'm trying to parse it like below but I'm only getting the last part '-M1'. Not quite familiar how to handle '_' in this case:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $Parent -Filter "Some Result_*.txt" -File -Recurse) | ForEach-Object{
    Rename-Item -Path $_.DirectoryName -NewName $_.BaseName.Split('Some Result_')[-1] -whatIf
}
```

Comment: Can you eleaborate and edit your question to give an expample of the folder structure? Are any folders that need to be re-named sub-folders of a folder that needs to be re-named? Are all folders that need to be renamed sub-folders of a single folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a simple structure such as:

```
C:\...\PARENT
├───folder1
│       Some Result_XYZ.txt
│
├───folder2
│       Some Result_ABC.txt
│
└───folder3
        Some Result_DEF.txt
```

The following would work:

```
$Parent = 'c:\...\Parent'
(Get-ChildItem -Path $Parent -Filter 'Some Result_*.txt' -File -Recurse) | ForEach-Object{
    Rename-Item -Path $_.DirectoryName -NewName $_.BaseName.Split('_')[-1] -whatIf
}
```

Note that the above `Rename-Item` has the `-WhatIf` switch specified so it can be safely tested. Remove the `-WhatIf` switch once you've verified the correct folders will be renamed.

Taking advantage of aliases and positional parameters, the above can be shortened to:

```
$Parent = 'c:\...\Parent'
(gci $Parent 'Some Result_*.txt' -af -s) | %{
    ren $_.DirectoryName $_.BaseName.Split('_')[-1] -whatIf
}
```

### Edit: Based on clarification

The following will extract everything after the first underscore in the filename:

```
$Parent = 'c:\...\Parent'
(Get-ChildItem -Path $Parent -Filter 'Some Result_*.txt' -File -Recurse) | ForEach-Object{
    Rename-Item -Path $_.DirectoryName -NewName ($_.BaseName -replace '^.+?_') -whatIf
}
```

The `-replace` operator uses regulare expressions for matching. The match string specifies:

- `^` - Match must start at the beginning of the string
- `.+` - Match a sequence of one or more characters with the exception of <NewLine>
- `?` - "Lazy" quantifier (matching stops at first underscore. Without this, everything up the *last* underscore would be matched)
- `_` - Literal underscore

References:

- [RegEx Cheat Sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)
- [-Replace operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Above in the description I added clarification and my next problem..

Comment: OK, so you need more than the "XYZ" portion. Is the "Some Result" portion of the filename always the same or does it vary? Does "Everything after the *first* underscore" better describe the portion of the BaseName you want to extract? Or is there a chance that it can contain underscores as well? Also are there any characters in any part of the name or path other than letters/digits/space/hyphen/underscore? (that would require using the `-LiteralPath` parameter)

Comment: Filenames do contain more underscores, but your last code edition works exactly the way I need it.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool. If it's all good, please mark my reply as `Answer`.